# Initialise DB:transaction in Repository Pattern for Laravel

Tags: laravel, repository-pattern

Is there anyway to initialise DB:transaction to repository pattern. As far as I have explored couldn't find any possible way to initialise in Repository methods. Please help with this to resolve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process is same. Let me share code for demo purpose. You may try this way.

```
      $this->model->title = $data['title_english'];        
      $this->model->slug = $data['slug'];

       $product = $this->model;

        try{
            DB::transaction(function() use ($product, $data) {
                $product->save();

                if(!empty($data['category'])){
                    foreach ($data['category'] as $category){
                        $product->categories()->attach($category);
                    }
                    unset($category);
                }
            });

            DB::commit();
        }catch(\Exception $e){
            DB::rollback();
        }
```

Comment: Hi Abdullah Al Shakib

Thank you for your response. Actually my method is as given below and want DB:transaction for this.

public function create(array $attributes)
    {
        
        return $this->getModel()->create($attributes);
    }

Comment: It should work. Try this. I only shared my repository code. From my side, i used this work flow controller->service->repository->do some action

Comment: With `DB::transaction` being used, the `DB::commit()` and `DB::rollback()` is surely completely redundant? Unless these are nested transactions of some sort?

Comment: @AbdullahAlShakib where do you use the DB::transaction? in service or in the repository?